# How to set cpuset.cpus dynamically?

Tags: virtualization, libvirt, cgroups

I have been trying to run a VM on some particular cpu cores. Now the thing is I can set cpuset with virt-install and that will reflect in VM's XML and it will define the affinity. But what about cpuset.cpus? That is inherited directly from the parent. Is there any way to set it when launching the VM? I mean, when I give the command virt-install, is there any option that can set cpuset.cpus dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virt-install` doesn't support pinning particular VCPUs to host's CPUs.  For this you have to use:

- either GUI tool `virt-manager`
- or edit the domain XML using `virsh edit <domain>` and set the pinning according to [CPU tuning options](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUTuning)